# Let $A = \{ (x,y) \mid y=e^x , x \in \Bbb R \}$, $B=\{ (x,y) \mid y=e^{-x} , x \in \Bbb R\}$ then

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- A : $A \cap B = \{\}$
- B : $A \cap B \ne \{\}$
- C : $A \cup B = \Bbb R^2$
- D : None of these

Comment: This is math.stack**exchange**, not math.stack**homework-help**

Comment: This is impossible to read. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Its not homework? Okay it's my doubt I know the answer but I think it's wrong

Comment: If you need help at least show us that you tried something...

Comment: Try plotting them on desmos.com

Comment: Also, if D is true, then it must be false since it is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that $A\cap B$ indicates to solving the equation: $$e^x = e^{-x}$$ which has only one real solution, $x =0$. Hence, **$A \cap B \neq \emptyset$**.

And, can you justify whether option $C$ is correct?

Comment: Good answer, but I think next time people should avoid answering questions which have low quality and the OP has not shown any research effort. +1

Comment: Thank you, @Landuros. Yes, **to the OP**, it is better to include all your efforts in the question itself.

Comment: Rohan A and be will be having (0,1) in common?? I did try to solve it but i was confused with this. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Infiee Yes, $A\cap B = \{(0,1)\}$.

Comment: So how come the answer says A∩B=∅?? In the book(I cant even upload the pic )

Comment: @Infiee Leave the book. Sometimes they may be wrong. You just think as to whether (0,1) is in both the sets or not..